# Win10 File Explorer shows a different Type after search

Tags: hard-drive, windows-explorer

I have an external drive (Seagate Ultra Touch HDD 2Gb) with a bunch of MP4 files. In File Explorer on Windows 10, I have Type and Length columns (among others) displayed in Detail view (and in Search results). The Type is "MP4 File" for all of these files, and the video length (H:MM:SS) is displayed. However, when I search for particular files, matching files show a Type of "WMP11.AssocFile.MP4", and the Length field shows empty.

Other than rebooting and restarting Explorer, I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it FAT32 or NTFS?

Comment: It is exFAT (the way it came out of the box).